# Sqlalchemy how to end connection to database to prevent deadlock

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, database-deadlocks

In my project, I'm listening to a kafka stream and putting the message into a database. I'm currently creating a scoped session to connect to my database. Is there a proper way to close the connection after the record load in order to avoid deadlocking?

I have a try-catch-finally block that does these things, but i'm wondering which one of them is actually necessary:

```
        session.flush()
        session.expire_all()
        session.expunge_all()
        session.remove()
        session.close_all()
```

If it helps, when I'm creating the connection, I'm also using connection pools with these settings:

```
 ENGINE = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'db2+ibm_db://{CONNECTION_STRING}', echo=False,
                                      pool_timeout=60, pool_recycle=30, pool_size=30, max_overflow=5,
```

Comment: You can minimise chances of deadlock or lock-timeouts by frequent commits, smaller batch sizes, optimal access plans for concurrent queries, and various other techniques. EDIT your question to add the Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) and Db2-server version, because some techniques are platform or version specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.commit()` or `session.close()` should be sufficient to release all locks held by the session.